# Android - NFC - transceive() - android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I'm using a IAS ECC card to encrypt (RSA) a hash SHA256 with my Android phone.
My APDU command:
`0x00 0x88 0x00 0x00 + one byte(lengh) + DIGEST_INFO_SHA2 (19 bytes) + HASH_SHA2 (32bytes)`

This command is executed successfully on a Android 4.4 phone > OK : I got my RSA 256 bytes.

But I got `android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost` while executing on Android 6.0 and later.

Any ideas may help. Thanks.